# Can a person have null name?

Tags: validation

I am writing an app that has a sign-up form. [This](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/) article made me doubt everything I knew about human names. My question is: does a person's name necessarily have positive length? Or can I validate names in this way and be confident that I have not denied anyone their identity?

P.S.: one might ask why am I validating at all. The answer is that this is for a school project and proper validation is a part of the mark. The article above proves that person's name can be pretty much any string of positive length but I don't know if zero length is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all types of programming, you have to draw a distinction between what is meaningful in the real world, and what is meaningful for your software solution.

How the data is to be used will validate what type of validation is required.

For instance, if your software interfaces with a government API, and the government API requires a first name and surname, you should do the same.

If you're interacting with bank accounts, you may have a single string which represents that account name, which many or may not be a human name or not, but may have other constraints around length.

If the name is only to be used for display purposes, maybe there is no point to capture the name at all, and instead you should capture a preferred display name (which doesn't needlessly assume a certain number of name components).

When writing software, you should target to make as few assumptions as possible, unless those assumptions will cause an increase in complexity of your software solution. If the software requires people to have non-empty names, then you should validate at the border that this is true.

In addition, if you were my student, you would have already lost marks for conflating null, and an empty string. In this instance, null would represent you lack data about the name, and an empty string would indicate that user has specified that their name is empty.

Also, if you decide not to validate something, you should at least leave a comment to indicate that you thought of it. If you do something unusual, it's possible a future developer may come along and fix the "bug". In addition, this helps you avoid losing marks.